# How do I get these hover effects but with diamonds instead of circles

Tags: css, shapes

I'm trying to get this exact effect, only thing is, I want to have the image and rollover shaped like a diamond as opposed to a circle.

Anyone know how I would go about this.

The code is all there, just asking how to make it diamond element/properties

WEBSITE & CODE HERE - http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/08/08/circle-hover-effects-with-css-transitions/

DIAMOND SHAPE LIKE THIS -

[image]

Comment: the effect is based almost on `scale` transform, so looks like you just need to know ***how to render a diamond shape***, also I think diamond has various kinds of shape, so you should be more specific about that.

Comment: @KingKing I found this -

#diamond {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border: 50px solid transparent;
 border-bottom-color: red;
 position: relative;
 top: -50px;
}
#diamond:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 left: -50px;
 top: 50px;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border: 50px solid transparent;
 border-top-color: red;
}

Comment: @KingKing I want the javascript to stay there but it seems to be not be working the javascript link. Any solutions?

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with javascript here, you obvisouly said it worked, now you said it did not work for no reason, I've tested on all browsers on my side there is no thing wrong. The last comment of yours shows that you turned off javascript and it stopped  working and you asked for why. I did explain that prefix-library need JS to run, that library does nothing more than appending the prefixes for you, so that you just need to write `transform` instead of writing all `-webkit-transform`, `-moz-transform`, `-ms-transform`, `transform`.  But now you said you want the javascript ???

Comment: @KingKing I said it worked when I saw your JSBin on the assumption it was going to work exactly how it does for you in my browser. However, it didn't. I repeat I want the javascript on and in, but even when I directly copy the code from your JSBin example, it doesn't work, that's why I mentioned if there was something wrong with the java link (the prefix) that's within the code.

Comment: have you tried adding all the  `-webkit-transform`, `-moz-transform`, ... (just replace `transform` with those, I hope you understand what browser-specific prefixes are and how to add them), also looks like you didn't not add the prefix-libary correctly while copying the code.

Comment: @I'm not really sure. I'm very new and completely inexperienced. Would you be able to help me out, if not I can try. Just like the last example you did on JSbin. Thanks a lot for your help so far, I really appreciate it

Comment: here I manually added all the prefixes versions, so we don't need the prefix library as well as javascript enabled http://jsbin.com/zevekulu/4/

Comment: @KingKing worked perfect!! Thanks so much! One more thing. In the examples shown here - http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/08/08/circle-hover-effects-with-css-transitions/ They have two different font types and a line to separate the two. How would I do go about making a header and then a small description, both different fonts? Would i need to implement some sort of <h1> or <p> tags?

Comment: You can put content inside the `.inner-content`, you should have a root `div` inside there and put the content inside that div like here http://jsbin.com/zevekulu/5/ . If you need different effects, you need to understand some CSS features such as `transition`, `animation`

Comment: @KingKing thanks so much for that. As for different effects I don't need any. Could you help me out with some code, just like you did there, but having two different font-families as opposed to colour?

Comment: that is simple just by adding property `font-family`, why can't you do it yourself? it's simple.

Comment: @KingKing haha so it is. Thanks a lot. You've made me understand the code a lot more. Before I close this of me being stupid and you being a life saver. Could you do the exact same but with example 2 FROM http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/08/08/circle-hover-effects-with-css-transitions/ I promise then that will be the last time I bother you :)

OH! And that line that divides the two pieces of text?

Comment: For the line added http://jsbin.com/zevekulu/8/ and here is the demo similar to the example 2, http://jsbin.com/zevekulu/9/ Adding more effects is not difficult when you have the base shape (in the first demo), you can even add more elements to the `.menu-item` with absolute position to help create richer effects, ... However it of  course requires time and your own efforts of researching and trying, asking consequently this way is not recommended.

Comment: @KingKing you are a star! Thank you so much for your patience and efforts. If I ever have another problem or question I'll come to you first. Yes I do agree, asking consequently is not recommended, but I did research and try a lot before I came here. Just nothing to do with diamond shapes. Thanks buddy. (Last thing - what effect do you think is better?)

Comment: it depends however I prefer the first.

Comment: @KingKing Just one other point, when i inset my own images, they seem to be stretched out and not very detailed. How do I change this?   - like the cat here - http://jsbin.com/codeya/1/  - it's quite strecthed is that to do with the 200% height and width?

Comment: it's because of `skew(-15deg,-15deg)` not being removed from `.diamond.chrome:after`, note that it's used only to ***de-skew*** the inner elements while the container element is skewed (with `skew(15deg,15deg)`), because you just need the square rotated, so no need to use `skew`, updated demo http://jsbin.com/favucova/1/ , you can change `background-size` to make it larger or smaller but it should be mimnimum at `70.71%`.

Comment: @KingKing it's a lot better. A lot! However it's still quite blurry/fuzzy not as sharp. Any other reasons potentially?

Comment: @KingKing also the text seems kinda fuzzy, is everything all good in terms of skewness and dimensions

Comment: if you run the demo on ***IE11***, it works perfectly. FireFox also renders the text sharply but the animation is not good (we have to wait for about 0.5s before it becomes sharp again). The reason is because of transforming, you know the text is transformed multi-times, the first round is by the parent's transform, and the second round is by its own transform (to de-rotate, de-translate, de-skew ...), so there may be some error in calculating the size of the text, also that's how webkit-browsers work, they always use ***anti-aliasing*** for the transformed text (it's not good of course)...

Comment: So we have to use a work-around, the text should not be put inside the `.inner-content` as we did before, we need to put it outside and right inside as a direct child of the `.content`, in this updated demo http://jsbin.com/favucova/3/ , I put all the text in `.text-content` element. It works perfectly now.

Comment: Okay, that's a great solution, thanks. That works perfect now. However, the image is still slightly fuzzy, is this due to the transforming at all or the anti-aliasing?

Comment: not sure if the image is blur or not, it seems OK to me, but if it is , of course it's because of the transforms, That's some kind of hard- to-fix issue. The examples at your link don't use complicated transforms (just `scale` on hovering), so the result should look better.

Comment: @KingKing Yeah it's not exactly blurry, its just not as sharp. But it's still okay. Just wondering if you would have any idea of how to make it sharper whether it be changing some of the transform stuff

Comment: sorry as I said, it's a hard problem, I don't quite have any idea. In fact I've encoutered this problem before, but it's not really serious and hard to fix, so I simply accept it. Also it's not a general problem, I see that ***IE11*** can handle this best while other browsers may render the transformed image a little blurredly.

Comment: you're right, it could be worse. It opens perfect on other computers, safari looks really crisp. Thanks for the help, I'll let you know when I've finished it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many demos in the link you posted. I just picked the first demo as an example. In fact all the demos there style the element as **circles**, which is simpler than shaping elements as **diamonds**. As I said before, the most important thing is how to render the diamond shape, it should have border and inner content (such as image background ...). That requirement makes it become more complicated than just a solid diamond. After shaping the element as diamond, you just need to apply the transform `scale` (from `0` in normal state to `1` in hover state). Of course we need many parts in the diamond menu item so we need some HTML elements to render it (1 element together with its pseudo-elements won't be able to render complicated shapes with rich interaction and effects ...). Here is the demo code, note that I just used `transform` property and use prefix-free library, you can add more prefixed versions of `transform` (such as `-webkit-transform`, `-moz-transform`, ...) if you don't want to use prefix-free library:

**HTML**:

```
<div class='menu-item'>
   <div class='diamond chrome'></div>
   <div class='content'>
     <div class='diamond clipper'>
        <div class='inner-content'>
          Diamond menu item
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.menu-item {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;        
  position:relative;    
  transform: translateY(100px) 
}
/* render diamond shape */
.diamond {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;top:0;
  transform:rotate3d(0,0,1,45deg) skew(15deg,15deg);        
}
/* the outside chrome which has the translucent white border 
 and the background image */
.diamond.chrome {
  overflow:hidden;        
}
/* render the background */
.diamond.chrome:before {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  background:url(http://placekitten.com/200/200);
  background-size:100% 100%;
  width:200%;
  height:200%;
  left:50%;top:50%;
  transform:  translate(-50%,-50%) skew(-15deg,-15deg) rotate3d(0,0,1,-45deg);
  z-index:-1;
}
/* render the translucent white border */
.diamond.chrome:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  left:0;top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;        
  box-shadow:0 0 0 20px rgba(255,255,255,.5) inset;
  transition:all 0.4s ease-in-out; 
}
/* animate the translucent border when hovering the menu item */
.menu-item:hover .chrome:after {
  box-shadow:0 0 0 0px rgba(255,255,255,.5) inset;
}
/* animate the inner content when hovering the menu item */
.menu-item:hover .content {        
  transform:scale(1);
  opacity:0.8;
}  
/* the content which should be scaled from 0 up to 1 
   to show up on hovering */
.menu-item .content {    
  color:white;
  opacity:0;
  font-size:20px;    
  transition:all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transform:scale(0);    
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;     
}
/* the clipper used to clip the inner content by the diamond shape */
.menu-item .clipper {
  overflow:hidden;
}
/* the inner content which contains text and other elements for interaction */
.menu-item .inner-content {
  background:teal;
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;    
  width:200%;
  height:200%;
  left:50%;top:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%) skew(-15deg,-15deg) rotate3d(0,0,1,-45deg);
}
/* this is used to align the text vertically */
.menu-item .inner-content:before {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

### [JsBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/zevekulu/1/)

Answer (score 0):

`#diamond:hover {border : 5px solid black; 
-webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
transform: rotateZ(45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(45deg);}`

Comment: Where does that go. Could you write the whole shabang out. I'm not sure where it all goes

Comment: @user3806447 , I didn't understand what you really want to do.

Comment: Could you please add explanation to why this is good solution to the problem.

Comment: (As far as I understood your question) above code in answer will rotate that div to 45º angle and it will be displayed as diamond.  I apologise if I didn't got your question

Comment: @Rahiil From the website example i provided. Instead of it being a circle, I want a simple diamond shape instead. I then asked if you could write the code within the examples from the website as I'm not sure where it may go

Comment: @King King wow that's awesome. Thats just what I want. One thing, how do I make the diamond equal length on both sides though. What parts of the css would I change? As if it were an equal square rotated, do you get me? Thanks for your help so far

Comment: @kingking Hey, thanks a lot. I worked it out, it's to do with the skewness. I got one more thing. In the examples there are two types of text and line dividing the two. Having two types of text is more important at this stage but how do I go about that. Could you do that on JSBin again? It's very clear that way, thank you

Comment: @king king It doesn't work when I open it in browser. It opens as a square with the correct hover effect but only a bit of the image shows too

Comment: @kingking would you like an image of what it looks like for me?

Comment: Okay I've managed to get it so everything works and that every is positioned fine. The only thing is. The whole thing is an equal square not a diamond. Any ideas?

Comment: I think it has something to do with the javascript? When I turn it off in the JS Bin you gave me, it does represents exactly what I have in my browser. What could this mean, is the Javascript not working?

Comment: @zb123 why did you leave the comments here? I did not receive any notifications from you. Turning off the Javascript will make ***prefix-free*** library stop working, hence all the `transform`s may not work, if you just want a pure CSS solution, try appending all the prefixes ***manually*** to the CSS code, such as `-webkit-transform`, `-moz-transform`, ...